# sum digit in string but how to do it if it start with negative sign?

Tags: python

I have this problem I did the positive but what about if it is a negative number and need to sum? Please help.

Question: Write a function called `sum_digits`.

Given a number, `sum_digits` returns the sum of all its digits.

```
output = sum_digits(1148)
print(output) # --> 14
```

If the number is negative, the first digit should count as negative.

```
output = sum_digits(-316)
print(output) # --> 4
```

Notes:

In order to use some of the methods that will be most helpful to you, you will most likely want to do some string to number conversion and vice versa.

Below is my function:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    num_sum = 0
    for i in num_str:
        dig = int(i)
        num_sum += dig

    return num_sum
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer; this tells others that the issue is resolved and helps others find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 1):

No need for string conversion. This works for positive and negative integers:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    if num < 0:
        return -sum_digits(-num)
    elif not num:
        return 0
    else:
        return num % 10 + sum_digits(num // 10)
```

If recursion isn't on the menu:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    factor, num, total = -1 if num < 0 else 1, abs(num), 0
    while num:
        total += num % 10
        num = num // 10
    return total * factor
```

Edit: someone pointed out you may only want the first digit subtracted, instead of having the result be negative, i.e. `-316` as `-3 + 1 + 6` instead of `-(3 + 1 + 6)`. If you do indeed want to subtract the first digit if the number is negative:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    factor, num, total = -1 if num < 0 else 1, abs(num), 0
    while num:
        total += num % 10 if num > 10 else factor * num
        num = num // 10
    return total
```

For the first 2 examples, the result for `-316` would be `-10`, for the last, the result would be `4`.

Comment: I think you missed the details in the OP. The sum for `-316` should be `-3 + 1 + 6`, not `-(3 + 1 + 6)`

Comment: You're right - I'm leaving the first two because it seems like the more common problem, but added the needed solution.

Answer (score 1):

If parsing number to string is okay with you solution this simple should be okay.

```
In [1]: def sum_digits(x):
   ...:     x = str(x)
   ...:     if x[0] == '-':
   ...:         return sum(map(int, [x[:2], *x[2:]]))
   ...:     return sum(map(int, x))

In [2]: sum_digits(1148)
Out[2]: 14
In [3]: sum_digits(-316)
Out[3]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def sum_digits(num):
...     negative = num < 0  # returns Boolean of if number is negative or not
...     if negative:
...         value_1 = int(str(num)[1])  # get the first numerical digit i.e. in -35, 3
...     num = str(abs(num))  # convert to modulus of number and to string
...     num_sum = sum(int(i) for i in num)  # sum of all the digits i.e. -35 = 8
...     if negative:
...         num_sum = num_sum - 2*value_1  # subtract 2*the first numerical digits i.e 8-(2*3) = 2
...
...     return num_sum
...
>>> """test cases"""
>>> print(sum_digits(316))
10
>>> print(sum_digits(-316))
4
```

A simple and logical solution

Answer (score 1):

One-liner just because:

```
sum(map(int, num[1:])) + (int(num[0]) if num[0] != '-' else int(num[0:2]) * 2)
```

This assumes `num` is a string, otherwise convert it to a string before using the above.

```
num = str(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if-statement to deal with the negative case.

```py
def sum_digits(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    num_sum = 0
    
    # Check if number is negative (first char is negative sign)
    if num_str[0] == "-":
        # If so, subtract first digit then remove the first two chars
        num_sum -= int(num_str[1])
        num_str = num_str[2:]
    
    # Number is now positive, so can deal with it accordingly
    for i in num_str:
        dig = int(i)
        num_sum += dig

    return num_sum

output = sum_digits(1148)
print(output) # --> 14

output = sum_digits(-316)
print(output) # --> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think such a simple problem should not be solved using str/int conversions, slices and other complex instruments. So, that's my solution:

```py
def sum_digits(num: int) -> int:
    is_negative = num < 0
    num = abs(num)
    num_sum = 0

    while num > 10:
        num_sum += num % 10
        num = num // 10
        
    if is_negative:
        num_sum -= num % 10
    else:
        num_sum += num % 10

    return num_sum
```